# subtract a few hours from a date in php

Tags: php

I am trying to echo the timestamp for a file using this:

```
Last updated: <?= date("m/d/Y H:i:s",filemtime("file1.html")) ?>
```

but this is on a server that is 6 hours ahead.

I've tried using DateTime::sub or date_sub or sub but none of these are being recognized. Do I need to call the date class or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filemtime` returns a timestamp, just subtract the number of seconds you need.

```
date("m/d/Y H:i:s",filemtime("file1.html")-6*3600)
```

or specify the timezone

```
$time = new Datetime(new Datetimezone('America/Chicago'));
$time->setTimestamp(filetime("file1.html"));
echo $time->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```